# How to split dvi output

Tags: display

I have a pc with 2 dvi outputs, a right and left monitor.

i also have a hdmi kvm switch that displays on my tv.

I would like to split each dvi output on my computer so that each monitor can be mirrored on my tv through a channel on the kvm switch. So lets say channel 1 on the switch would be the right monitor and channel 2 would be the left.

I tried using this [http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-1-Feet-DVI-D-Splitter-Cable/dp/B00111CTLA/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00111CTLA)...

but it failed, one monitor was completely green and the other was displaying distorted images and static.﻿

is there any other way to accomplish what im trying to do?

Comment: I am assuming your TV doesn't have DVI or VGA ports? Are you trying to hook it up via analog (the yellow plug)?

Comment: the tv only has hdmi, also the kvm switch has other inputs that are being displayed on the tv

Comment: In theory, the product you linked to should work, but I'm wondering about the power from the video card to the DVI ports... As it needs enough power to send to two displays on each DVI port...

Comment: Actually your post is unclear.  Do you want to send each DVI output to both a computer monitor and to the TV (through a KVM switch)?  That splitter cable is a kludge that would work in a few situations (e.g. split the DVI-A from the DVI-D), but more likely not work in others (e.g. try to split DVI-D to two destinations).  The proper way to do what you want is to use an HDMI switch box (with active electronics).  Use DVI-to-HDMI adapters.  Since you have 2 inouts and 3 outputs, you'll probably need to get a 4x4 switch.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is a DVI splitter with HDCP, and possibly a DVI-HDMI scan-converter  (and probably a DVI-HDMI adapter without the converter).

The problem is that DVI talks with your computer to tell it what the resolution and scan rate of your monitor is, as well as synch the signal.  The splitter you're using is not capable of dealing with resolution and scan rate differences.

DVI to HDMI is easy, it's basically a connector change.

2x monitors from each DVI feed needs some logic to deal with it.  Although, if you were to run four identical monitors, you *might* be able to get away with a couple of simple splitters (though I doubt it).  You'll want to set the computer monitor resolution to match the TV resolution too.  If they're different, you'll need a converter for that part too.  You could double check to make sure that your computer monitor settings match TV with the splitter you've got.  And refresh rate too.  You might get lucky and have it work.